# Could arara detect the file size?

Tags: arara, ghostscript

I have a large book with many chapters, lots figures and tikz pictures and some of them have really large file sizes (over 100MB). I utilize `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` to get the chapters from GitHub and visualize the pdf on the browser. The problem is that there is a limit on file size of 20MB.

I currently use `ghostscript` to reduce file sizes, and I've recently discovered `arara` and read in the documentation that there is support for `gs`. I was wondering if it was possible to create a conditional using `arara` to run `gs` only if the file size is over 20MB.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's not too difficult but you have to create an own rule or rely on implementation details. I'm sure @PauloCereda will provide an answer soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible to exploit the underlying `File` class. For testing purposes, let us create a file of exactly 20MB:

```bash
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ truncate -s 20MB foo.dat
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ ls -l foo.dat
-rw-rw-r--. 1 paulo paulo 20000000 ago  8 10:46 foo.dat
```

Now, let's create a very simple TeX file:

```
Hello
\bye
```

And add the following directives:

```
% arara: pdftex if toFile('foo.dat').length() <= 20000000
% arara: xetex if toFile('foo.dat').length() < 20000000
```

We are exploiting `toFile(...)`, which returns a `File` object and then using the `length()` method which gives us the total of bytes of that particular file. The first directive will run PDFTeX if, and only if, the size of `foo.dat` is less or equal 20MB (20,000,000 bytes). Similarly, the second directive will run XeTeX if, and only if,  the size of `foo.dat` is less than 20MB.

Running `arara test.tex` will give us

```bash
[paulo@cambridge ~] $ arara test.tex
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Processing "test.tex" (size: 129 B, last modified: 08/08/2021
11:00:38), please wait.

(PDFTeX) PDFTeX engine .................................. SUCCESS

Total: 0.45 seconds
```

which should be expected, as the size of `foo.dat` is equal to 20MB. This trick could be used in the rule context as well. Hope this could act as a starting point. `;)`